# What is the difference between a rigid motion and an isometry?

Tags: geometry

Can those two terms be used interchangeably?

Comment: Rigid motions exclude reflections, isometries do not.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same thing, despite the confusion made by some textbooks (especially geometry textbooks for middle schools, for instance). Your right hand is isometric to your left hand$^{(*)}$, since there is a transformation preserving distances (the term *isometry* comes from Greek, the prefix *iso* stands for *analogous* and the suffix stands for *distance*) that brings your right hand into your left hand. However, there is no way to exactly overlap them in the plane, since they have different orientations (from which the *right hand rule* for computing $\omega\wedge r$, for instance). Less informally, a transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an isometry if the associated matrix is orthogonal (we can easily check that this is equivalent to preserving distances) and a rigid motion if, additionally, the determinant is $+1$.

<sup>(*) More or less. For instance my right middle finger is about 2mm longer than my left middle finger, and I guess I am not the only one affected by such kind of asymmetry.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever made this distinction myself ... and this is my field! I suppose I should be more careful. Certainly, "rigid motion" connotes a continuous, shape-(and-orientation-)preserving *journey* from one position to another; a reflection, in contrast, involves a discrete (orientation-reversing) *jump*. Then again, as a reflection in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be achieved via a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the whole journey-vs-jump distinction is ultimately moot. Thus, admitting reflections to the Rigid Motions Club early-on amounts to *foreshadowing* the broader context. :)