# What is the difference between isometry and rigid motion?

Tags: geometry

My teacher say that they are the same thing because the transformation that they both preserve distance and measurement of angels but just the isometry have opposite isometry and direct isometry, where the opposite isometry doesn't preserve the oreientation. So are they still the same?

Comment: A reflection is an isometry but not a rigid motion.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang how is a reflection not a rigid motion? Doesn't the length remains the same?

Comment: Never mind.  For some reason I thought rigid motions consisted of rotations and translations only.  Now Google tells me many people define rigid motions and isometries as synonyms.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang oh wew .-. So they are the same right?

Comment: It depends on the local definitions. For me, rigid motions are represented by $SO(2)$ and isometries are represented by $O(2)$, so they are distinct things. In particular, rigid motions cannot change the sign of an oriented area, so a symmetry with respect to a line is not a rigid motion (that makes sense, you cannot perform such a symmetry in the plane by just sliding or rotating a given shape).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a rigid motion and an isometry?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371468/what-is-the-difference-between-a-rigid-motion-and-an-isometry)

Answer (score 5):

To echo the comments, first, it does indeed depend on the local definitions. What your teacher meant by "rigid motion" is probably an orientation-preserving isometry.

For a mundane example: if you have a pair of gloves, there is an isometry which transforms the left-hand glove into the right-hand one (think of mirror image), but there is no such "rigid motion" (as anyone knows who ever tried to put a glove on the wrong hand).